# Python Tkinter how to make a text box scroll

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I wrote the following code to quickly grab and display information from Wikipedia. It works great unless the Wiki summary contains more information than the box can display. I thought adding sticky = N+S+E+W would fix this but it doesn't appear to be doing anything. How can I update this code to make it scroll if there is too much information to display in the text box all at once?

enter code here

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import wikipedia

def search_wiki():
    txt = text.get()           # Get what the user entered into the box
    txt = wikipedia.page(txt)  # Search Wikipedia for results
    txt = txt.summary          # Store the returned information
    lblText = Label(main, text=txt,justify=LEFT,wraplength=600, fg='black',
                    bg='white', font='times 12 bold').grid(row = 50,
                    column = 1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

main = Tk()
main.title("Search Wikipedia")
main.geometry('750x750')
main.configure(background='ivory3')
text = StringVar()

lblSearch = Label(main, text = 'Search String:').grid(row = 0, column = 0,
                                                      padx = 0, pady = 10)
entSearch = Entry(main, textvariable = text, width = 50).grid(row = 0,
                                                              column = 1)

btn = Button(main, text = 'Search', bg='ivory2', width = 10,
             command = search_wiki).grid(row = 0, column = 10)


main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your title mentions a textbox, but tkinter has nothing by that name. It has a `Text` widget and an `Entry` widget, both which can be used to edit data. It has a `Label` widget to display text. Are you asking about scrolling a `Text` widget, or asking how to scroll one or more `Label` widgets?

Comment: I'm new to tkinter so maybe I have thee terminology wrong. What I want to do is have line 9 of my code posted above so all the lines of text even if there is more text than fits. A scroll bar would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute you label with a more appropriate widget such as

```
lblText = ScrolledText(main,
                      bg='white',
                      relief=GROOVE,
                      height=600,
                      #width=400,
                      font='TkFixedFont',).grid(row = 50,
                      column = 1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
```

Comment: "how to make a text box scroll" which text box? I read lblText = Label then I've thought that a ScrolledText was a better choice. In my opinion ;)

Comment: Hi, I tried the above code but am receiving an error.   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wikipedia_gui.py", line 12, in <module>
    lblText = ScrolledText(main,
NameError: name 'ScrolledText' is not defined

Comment: BTW: I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows 10 if that matters.

Comment: you must before import it.....from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

Comment: I tried the above and get     import ScrolledText
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ScrolledText'     Thanks

Comment: it's very strange  https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html#module-tkinter.scrolledtext

Comment: This is getting stranger, I added from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText and now get  lblText = ScrolledText(main,
NameError: name 'main' is not defined   ???

Comment: @DaveMathews move `lblText` outside the function and add `global txt` at the start of the function

Comment: You don't need the `ScrolledText` widget. Just a standard `Text` widget is sufficient. It takes only a couple lines of code to hook it up to a scrollbar.

Comment: I got it to work by adding this code to the function                                                                global texw
    textw = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(main,width=90,height=50)
    textw.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky=N+S+E+W)
    textw.insert(END, txt)                                                                                             The only problem now  I can't seem to get it to word wrap. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all your help. I finally figured everything out. Here is my new code in case anybody else runs into this or something similar.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from wikipedia import *

def search_wiki():
    txt = text.get()           # Get what the user eneterd into the box
    txt = wikipedia.page(txt)  # Search Wikipedia for results
    txt = txt.summary          # Store the returned information
    global texw
    textw = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(main,width=70,height=30)
    textw.grid(column=1, row=2,sticky=N+S+E+W)
    textw.config(background="light grey", foreground="black",
                 font='times 12 bold', wrap='word')
    textw.insert(END, txt)

main = Tk()
main.title("Search Wikipedia")
main.geometry('750x750')
main.configure(background='ivory3')

text = StringVar()

lblSearch = Label(main, text = 'Search String:').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
entSearch = Entry(main, textvariable = text, width = 50).grid(row = 0,
                                                          column = 1)

btn = Button(main, text = 'Search', bg='ivory2', width = 10,
             command = search_wiki).grid(row = 0, column = 10)

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display text that is scrollable, you should use a `Text` widget. You cannot scroll a `Label`, and scrolling a group of `Labels` is relatively difficult. The `Text` widget is by far the best choice for scrollable text.

Comment: I tried changing the Label to Text but it's not working, probably due to my lack of understanding tkinter at this point. In my function I changed lines 9-11 to,            T = Text(main, height=20, width=40)
    T.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    T.insert(END, txt)                                                                                                      Which gives me an error _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid. I tried removing the pack() and the error goes away but nothing is displayed.